# Is it possible to run an Asp.net web application (web forms app) from last successful build in IIS server app pool (production)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My application got some serious problems regarding to asp.net version and other Nuget miss much versions and I can't build it due to these incompatibilities. I am looking for a solution to run my app in production server from last successful compiled build.

The application has developed in asp.net version 4.0, Visual Studio 2010.

Is that possible or not? I do not have no time for rebuilding.

Comment: the application has developed in asp.net version 4.0 , visual studio 2010

Comment: Do you have a backup of the binaries from the last successful build? If yes, use that. If no, are you using source control? If yes, get the version which you know was working and deploy that. If no, you are out of luck and you need to manually remove all the errors until you are the working point and build that and deploy. There is not other way.

Comment: right now when i try to build application it raise an error says [there was buid errors. would you like to continue and run the last successful build?] if i press yes so the application runs without error and it runs my application from [bin] directory for the app. so it means the dlls are exist on there but what i want is to run the application from this last successful build

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work for a web application because the compiler does not generate DLLs for everything. The views are compiled when the request arrives for them. Do you not have the old DLLs in your iis folder?

Comment: the server has hacked and all files were removed and now i am here assigned to work and fix the problem. the only think i have is the application where that faces build errors.

Comment: One more option you have is to look in the temporary folder and see if copies are there (on the server, or your dev machine). Look in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` but you will have to dig and find which folder is for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLL will not be created, in this case you will be able open page in browser